# i get same id in array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have recursive menu function from DB.
I add some jquery codes to it.
I click plus symbol then i can see all parent nodes.

I will add: add edit delete record buttons to popover later.
I created click function to fa fa-cog, but it is always show to same id on alert.

I try from 2 days but i can not display correct clicked id in the jquery script codes. 
i wanna display correct id in popover `<a href="<?php echo $Linkid ;?>"</a>` window. Thanks.

```
<?php
// Select all entries from the menu table
$result=mysqli_query($baglan, "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY sira ASC");
// Create a multidimensional array to conatin a list of items and parents
$menu = array(
    'items' => array(),
    'parents' => array()
);
// Builds the array lists with data from the menu table
while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    // Creates entry into items array with current menu item id ie. $menu['items'][1]
    $menu['items'][$items['id']] = $items;
    // Creates entry into parents array. Parents array contains a list of all items with children
    $menu['parents'][$items['kat_id']][] = $items['id'];
}


// Menu builder function, parentId 0 is the root
function buildMenu($parent, $menu)
{
$html = "";
$buton = '<a class="buton"><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button> </a>';
   if (isset($menu['parents'][$parent])){
$html .= "<ul>";
$html .= '<div class="left" id="nav">';
    foreach ($menu['parents'][$parent] as $itemId){
      if(!isset($menu['parents'][$itemId])){
$Linkid = $menu['items'][$itemId]['id'];
$ayarbuton = '<a class="goster" id="'.$Linkid.'" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'.$Linkid.'"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></button> </a>';
$html .="<div class='editRecord'";
 $html .= "<li>".$ayarbuton.$menu['items'][$itemId]['isim'].$menu['items'][$itemId]['id']."</li>";
$html .="</div>";

 }

    if(isset($menu['parents'][$itemId])){
$Linkid = $menu['items'][$itemId]['id'];
$html .= "<div class='bs-example'><div id='myTooltips'>";
$ayarbuton = '<a class="goster" id="'.$Linkid.'" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'.$Linkid.'"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></button> </a>';

$html .= "<li>".$buton.$ayarbuton . $menu['items'][$itemId]['isim']." ID = " .$Linkid;
$html .= buildMenu( $itemId, $menu );
$html .= "</div></div></li>";

           }
        }

$html .= '</div>';
$html .= "</ul>";
   }
   return $html;
}
echo buildMenu(0, $menu);
global $Linkid;
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".goster").click(function(){
    var linkID = $(".goster").attr("id");   
     alert(linkID);

$("#myTooltips a").tooltip({
    template : '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-head"><h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <a href="<?php echo $Linkid ;?>"></a><?php echo $Linkid ;?></h3></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
    });    

});

   });
</script>


<script>
  $('#nav .buton').css({cursor: "pointer"}).on('click', function(){

 var txt = $(this).html() == '<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button> '?'<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button> ':'<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button> ';

  $(this).html(txt);
  $(this).nextAll('ul').eq(0).slideToggle('fast');
            })
</script>
```

Comment: Please reduce your postet code to the important and not working parts. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

With `".goster"` selector you are selecting all the elements having `goster` class but no way of determine which one was actually clicked. 
In order to get the specific clicked element, you can use `this` in the `click` callback. Try change your handler to

```
  $(".goster").click(function(e){
    var linkID = this.id; 
    alert(linkID);
  });
```

Comment: Should use `this.id` or `e.currentTarget.id`. The `target` will be the child `<button>`

Comment: Ok that good, how can i display that id in to MYLINK in this script:   <pre><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".goster").click(function(e){
    var linkID = e.currentTarget.id; // e.target is the clicked element
    alert(linkID);
  });

    
  $("#myTooltips a").tooltip({
        template : '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-head"><h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <a href="MYLINK"></a>TOOLTIP</h3></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
    });    
 
});

</script></pre>

Comment: I'm sorry but this code is not clear. I just put a working example here https://codepen.io/dariospadoni/pen/yKdVxG Try to clean your code and put it into a fiddle to get better help

Comment: No problems, just use codepen for instance to show the actual output of your php code if my example still is not working for you

Answer (score 0):

finaly i will do it,
thanks all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".goster").click(function(e){
    var linkID = e.currentTarget.id; // e.target is the clicked element
    $(".goster").attr("href", linkID); // this will change the link URL
  });


  $("#myTooltips a").tooltip({
        template : '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-head"><h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <a href="linkID"></a>TOOLTIP</h3></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
    });    

});

</script>
```